# ng-model value is always String type, even entered value is a number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
</div>`

"test" value is always String type, even if entered a number that is valid case.
But still i want to get Its exact data type.

Can anyone suggest me a way to find its data type, if enter value is number then data Type should be "Number", and if enter value is "Abc" data type should be "String" and etc.

In short use the same html texture and get the data type of entered value

Comment: Based on comments to answers below, I'm guessing you want to keep the type checking to the controllers?  And you want to keep the input type dynamic so that you can use `type="text"` but still treat the value as a number later?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to post a bit of code to give an example, otherwise it's going to be difficult to give you an answer. I suspect it's because of bad html, i.e.,

```
<input type="text" />
```

The above will return a 'string'.

```
<input type="number" />
```

The above will return a 'number'. Is your code set correctly?

Edit: if you to simply put  without caring the 'type' (bad html) you could check the type in your controller when you're massaging the data. I.e., (using lodash for example) these two examples:

```
if (_.isString(value)) { }
if (_.isNumber(value)) { }
```

Or with native javascript simply use 'typeof'.

Another thought it, if you only have the choice of type="text", then in your controller you could use a RegEx on the incoming string, looking specifically for numbers.

```
if (value.match(/^\d+$/)) {
  // This should be a 'number';
}
```

Comment: My question is simple, it is a text field, that I know, now i had entered some value in this text field and entered value can be anything
like string or number or decimal value.

I need a way to find out the data Type of entered value instead of caring what kind of input type field it is.

Hoping for some positive answer from you.

Comment: @KusumKushwaha Could you please elaborate your answers little bit more and show some of your code? Thing is what is the purpose of your code ?What do you want to do with it ? Do you need to validate the inputs or something else? May be the approach of solving a particular issue can be made more efficient.

Comment: Yes, this is why the input tag has the attribute 'type' (ie type="text", type="number" etc)

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="getDataType(test)"/>
$scope.getDataType() = function(value) {  $scope.dataType = null;
       if( angular.isString(value) ) {  $scope.dataType = "String"}  
       if( angular.isNumber(value) ) { $scope.dataType = "Number" }
}; when I debugged my code, I found value is coming as "123" in case I had typed number and "abc" in case I had type string in text field. So my first condition will be true always and it will never enter in second condition.

Comment: But my requirement is, I have only one field that is of type text, and still i need to set the $scope.dataType, but whatever is set by user.

Comment: @Suraj Singh, hope you understand it now.

Please do needful help.

Comment: I don't think, my question deserve a negative marks, it is good question.
I had solved this problem.
var getDataType = function( value ) {
  var type;
  
  if(isNaN(value)) {
   type = "String";
  } else {
   type = "Number";
  }
  return type;
 };

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own function to test this (unless you already use a library that has a similar function).

For instance, you could do it like this:

```js
function isNumber(string) {
  var float = parseFloat(string);

  return !isNaN(float) && float.toString().length === string.length;
}

console.log(isNumber('365'));          // true
console.log(angular.isNumber('365'));  // false
console.log(typeof '365');             // string
console.log(typeof parseFloat('365')); // number
console.log(isNaN(parseFloat('365'))); // false

console.log(isNumber('365 days in a year'));          // false
console.log(angular.isNumber('365 days in a year'));  // false
console.log(typeof '365 days in a year');             // string
console.log(typeof parseFloat('365 days in a year')); // number
console.log(isNaN(parseFloat('365 days in a year'))); // false

console.log(isNumber('There are 365 days in a year'));          // false
console.log(angular.isNumber('There are 365 days in a year'));  // false
console.log(typeof 'There are 365 days in a year');             // string
console.log(typeof parseFloat('There are 365 days in a year')); // number
console.log(isNaN(parseFloat('There are 365 days in a year'))); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**edit:**
I created a simple function that tests if it is a number, I do not use `angular.isNumber`.

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-change="getDataType(test)"/> $scope.getDataType() = function(value) { $scope.dataType = null; if( angular.isString(value) ) { $scope.dataType = "String"} if( angular.isNumber(value) ) { $scope.dataType = "Number" } }; when I debugged my code, I found value is coming as "123" in case I had typed number and "abc" in case I had type string in text field. So my first condition will be true always and it will never enter in second condition.
Please try improving this code,
It will be great help.

Comment: I do not make use of `angular.isNumber`, added it for clarity

Comment: Thanks for answering, your answer helped me a lot to solve my problem.